# illustrator cut text from a shape with a brush

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, stroke, brush

I have a rectangle with a brush applied like this: [image: box]

I then put some text on top of the shape like here:
[image: box and text]

I want to subtract text from that shape so that it is cut out.  when I use pathfinder => subtract, it applies the brush stroke to the subtracted shape as you can see here: 
[image: box with text subtracted]

I'm wondering if there's any way to remove the text WITHOUT it applying the brush stroke to the text.  i just want to cut the text out of the shape.

Answer (score 3):

Select the shape

Choose `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu

> This separates the brush stroke from the shape and expands the brush, creating an independent object, then groups the stroke object with the underlying shape.

Proceed to cut the text, the brush won't be applied to the counter/hole left by the text.

Comment: perfect!  thanks for the quick reply!  so quick i have to wait to accept the answer! :)